# Some error while executing the below program

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n= int(input())
x = int(input())
for i in range (1,x+1):
   print()
   a = 0
   while(a<=x):
       for j in range((i*n),(i*n)+a):
           print(j,end="")
           a+=1
```

if i run the program it does not give an output but taking infinite inputs
please tell me the errors and give your program for the below question
The program must accept two integer value n and x as input and print the output in the desired pattern:

Example input/output

input:

```
8 5
```

output:

```
8  
16 17  
24 25 26  
32 33 34 35  
40 41 42 43 44
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `a` is initialized as `0` so your inner `for` loop never executes as `range((i*n),(i*n)+a)` generates nothing, and the `a+=1` statement never gets executed, resulting in an infinite `while` loop.

You can use a nested `for` loop instead:

```
n = int(input())
x = int(input())
for i in range(1, x + 1):
    for j in range(i):
        print(i * n + j, end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the problems is that, you did not increase a. Thus, `while(a<=x):` is infinite

Comment: sorry i forgotten to mention a+=1 in my question

Comment: Another issue is that, since your min value and max value in range(min_value, max_value) is the same, I mean (i*n) and (i*n)+a are the same when is a, It does not go through this for.